# How to display dynamic data in ViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm

In `Swift` I have `Realm DB`. And in my data base I have 10 items of data (news title) from server. Now I need display my data from `Realm DB` dynamical in `ViewController`

Answer (score 1):

As per your code

```
for indexes in newsObj {
    newsLable.text = indexes.newsTitle
}
```

if you have 10 news in your newsObj till it display only 10th new text if you want to display 10 news then

write this

```
let indexes = newsObj[index]
newsLable.text = indexes.newsTitle
```

Remove this code

```
for indexes in newsObj {
newsLable.text = indexes.newsTitle
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you are calling the below method for each index:

```
func elementAtScrollViewIndex(index: Int)
```

So the for loop is getting called 10 times for each index. As a result, label is displaying the title of 10th news for each index.

Simply remove the for loop and you can do the following:

```
newsLable.text = newsObj[index].newsTitle
```